# Dynamic search results in Android App using SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

I'm new to Android development and i would like to make a single activity to show featured results using Youtube API and when a search query is typed, i want to update the same list with search results.
I got stuck in my first step, which is configuring the SearchView and receiving data from it. After adding a SeachView to the layout, i made a reference for it in the Activity java code, then internet documentation went too fuzzy for and i couldn't understand what should i do in my case (dynamic results).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make listView's adapter extend from [**Filterable**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html), and use its [**getFilter()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html#getFilter%28%29) function according to the query that is changing in the SearchView, using the function [**setOnQueryTextListener()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setOnQueryTextListener%28android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener%29) .

it's that easy.

i also suggest that you watch the "[**the world of listView**](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html)" lecture in case you want to learn some tips about using a listView. they also explain how the filter works.